# Website <title> element max character length

Tags: html

just a little question.

How long can a website title be?

[Like this one:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opi3z.png)

Comment: are you talking about the `<title>` tag contents?

Comment: Yes thats it @Martin

Comment: *See* https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the link, helped alot @BillBell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimal title length. Google typically displays the first **50–60 characters** of a title tag. If you keep your titles under 60 characters, it will display your Title Properly and i hope this answer help you..

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the `<title>` element, this is actually an interesting question - there is **no set maximum** but there is a [guidance from  W3C](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html) that :

> Whilst there is no limit on the length of a title (...), information providers are warned that it may be truncated if long.

Also stating `<title>` text content should not exceed 64 characters (*in 1992*).

Reading the specs. for HTML4 and HTML5, and reading browser inspectors on this page and others, the `<title>` text is simply a text field and various HTML command structures are not agknowledged within it.

So; the outcome is that the title element can be as long as you like, but you have no guarentee that any part after the first 64 characters would be agknowledged by any particular browser, reader or other end point user.

References:

- [W3 Title Element Meta Data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#the-title-element)
- [W3 Title Element Style Guide](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html)
- [MDN Title Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTitleElement)
- [W3 Document Metadata](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#elementdef-title)
- [W3 DOM text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#text-content)

## UPDATE:

I have just generated a random text block of 30kb characters and this was loaded into an HTML page and output in full by the browser. Moreover, this was not invalid when parsed against the [HTML5 validator](https://html5.validator.nu).

Comment: The homepage for that styleguide says *This document was written in the early days of the web (1992), defining such terms as "webmaster", the "www.xxx.com" convention, and a few basic points which are just as valid today.  It has not been updated to discuss recent developments in HTML., and is out of date in many places, except for the addition of a few new pages, with given dates.*

Comment: @Quentin yes but it's the only place that I could find that declares any centralised number of min or max length of the `<title>` element

Comment: It's still an opinion from a quarter of a century ago.

Comment: @Quentin Yes.... I fully accept that but there is no other guidance given. Age isn't always a bad thing

Comment: It is important to consider how opinions are formed. The page you link to even explains why the recommendation is for 64 characters — that's as long as you could expect a title to be displayed in 1992 without it being truncated.

Comment: I have half a dozen tabs open on my browser right now, the title of this page is truncated after 14 characters. If I hover over the tab with the longest title that I have open right now, it comfortably displays 132 characters (I haven't tested how high it will go). Whichever of those two numbers you pick "64 because that is when it is truncated in title bars" is not good guidance for 2018.

Comment: Incidentally, the < 64 characters advice also appeared in the HTML 2.0 spec.

Answer (score 2):

Look - it's a Title, not an essay - keep it short, descriptive and punchy and you'll have no problems. Ultimately it is limited by whatever browser you use - and you could waste a significant part of your life testing all possibilities. My tip is: keep it simple - you probably can't predict the width of the screen / browser.